# How to decouple validators from controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing

I've been building Spring MVC (3.2/4.0) controllers with validators for my web application along the lines of what I found in the Spring Petclinic sample application.  However, in the example application, validators are created within the relevant controlllers using the `new` keyword, creating a tight coupling. Now that I'm writing tests to cover this code it is proving difficult to isolate these classes due to this coupling.

Is there a recommended way to decouple validators from controllers? Is there some other solution to this problem?

Here's an example from the Petclinic application of the tight coupling I mean:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    new PetValidator().validate(pet, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "pets/createOrUpdatePetForm";
    } else {
        this.clinicService.savePet(pet);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/owners/{ownerId}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237159/spring-mvc-constraint-validation-with-annotations-error-messages-not-display

Answer (score 1):

Define Petvalidator as a bean in your application-context and make the following changes to your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    PetValidator petValidator;   //change this line
    petValidator.validate(pet,result);  //change this line

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "pets/createOrUpdatePetForm";
    } else {
        this.clinicService.savePet(pet);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/owners/{ownerId}";
    }
}
```

And you can use property injection to inject the appropriate Petvalidator to your controller. If ur using component-scanning add the following to autowire the registered bean into your controller.

```
@Autowired
PetValidator petValidator;
```

Inside your controller istead of  `PetValidator petvalidator;`

Answer (score 0):

That's what `@Valid`is for:

```
public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("pet") @Valid Pet pet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
```

There's no need to do the validation yourself. Let Spring handle it automatically.

Comment: No it's not. @Valid enables JSR-303 bean validation. If his bean isn't annotated with constraints it will not work.

Comment: @Bart Bean validation is enabled via the application context and the existence of an implementation in the classpath. `@Valid` just tells Spring to validate the annotated object. No `@Valid`, no automatic validation. Feel free to read the docs or the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If your PetValidator is of type [org.springframework.validation.Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) you could bind it using `WebDataBinder.setValidator()`.

In your controller or @ControllerAdvice add a method annotated with @InitBinder.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // Add the validator. Could be an auto wired instance as well.
    binder.setValidator(new PetValidator());
}
```

Now all objects of a type supported by your validator will be validated automatically.